# How can my program react to changes in a TDateTimePicker?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, datetimepicker

I would like to know how to change a label's caption when the user chooses a particular date from the TDateTimePicker component.

Say for example:
If 06/02/2012 was marked on the TDateTimePicker component, label1's caption would become 'Hello World' otherwise nothing would happen if it was any other date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write an `OnChange` event handler for the date time picker. You will also need to make sure that this event handler is run when the form first shows:

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateDateTimeLabel;
var
  SelectedDate, SpecialDate: TDateTime;
begin
  SelectedDate := DateTimePicker1.DateTime;
  SpecialDate := EncodeDate(2012, 2, 16);
  if IsSameDay(SelectedDate, SpecialDate) then
    Label1.Caption := 'Hello World'
  else
    Label1.Caption := '';
end;

procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateDateTimeLabel;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateDateTimeLabel;
end;
```

Comment: That's just so that I can compare a date. It removes the time portion from the TDateTime variable. There's probably a much cleaner way but I know nothing much about delphi date time routines.

Comment: OK, there's a cleaner version using IsSameDay from the DateUtils unit.

Comment: `StrToDate` depends on `ShortDateFormat` and `DateSeparator`. You should better use `EncodeDate(2012, 2, 16)`

Comment: @kobik Thanks. My excuse is that this code was a lash up! I've changed it now as you suggest.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You can also use `ReplaceTime()` to set the time portion to 0, which is effectively the same as `Floor()` stripping it off.

Comment: @Remy I'm learning oh so much about dates and times today! Thanks.